# Desenvolvimento android studio

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para obter uma ação numa ImageView , coloquei um personagem dentro dela e queria que ele pulasse .
Relembrando , estou desenvolvendo um game no  Android Studio.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Olá, por favor podia ser mais explicito? Com imagens e algum do código por favor? Senão torna-se dificil

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txt_animacao"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/animacao"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: Coloquei dentro da imagemView uma animação, onde quero colocar uma ação de pulo . Meu game tem o intuito de o personagem pular  por cima de obstáculos se ele encostar em algum game over , senão ele continua.....

Comment: Não ponha o código aqui, ponha no tópico de forma identada e ponha por exemplo uma imagem do resultado aqui por favor.

Comment: O intuito da ImageView é **mostrar uma imagem** , não foi planeada com o intuito de criar animações de personagens ou algo do género. Podes tentar fazer algo com isso, mas na realidade vais estar a ter muito trabalho enquanto podias usar algum tipo de library como libgdx.

Comment: Mas se eu fosse usar uma ImagemView para essa função como começaria  o meu código?

Comment: Setando o valor da altura?

Comment: Mas queres que te diga a forma como eu fazia? Ou o código que eu utilizava?

Comment: O código que tu utilizava!

Comment: Por gentileza .

Comment: Pois não tenho base de como começar.

Comment: Então eu vou responder à sua pergunta em baixo

Comment: Esperarei a sua resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Eu aconselho avidamente **a não utilizar uma ImageView** para efeitos de animação e sim uma library como libgdx que tem suporte e facilidade.

Mas a lógica que eu utilizava seria esta por **duas ImageView**. **Uma ImageView** que estaria de fundo e ocuparia o ecrã inteiro em **fullscreen**. E uma ImageView que corresponderia ao personagem que estaria na parte de baixo do ecrã.

Algo como:

***layout.xml***

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" >
    <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/char"
          android:layout_width="largura da personagem"
          android:layout_height="altura da personagem">
   </ImageView>
</ImageView>
```

***main.java***

```
 int number=100;
 //number corresponderia à posição atual da personagem e a maneira como mudaria no jogo
 ImageView s = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.char);
 s.setY(number);
 s.setX(number)
```

Espero ter encaminhado na lógica de jogo

Comment: Então terei de colocar duas ImageView e logo após colocar duas imagens dentro delas certo ? .

Comment: Quando quis dizer fullscreen  , corresponderia uma imagem atrás da outra?

Comment: Sim duas ImageView com uma imagem em cada uma. Uma ficaria sempre atrás a servir de background e outra que seria o personagem

Comment: Bom dia ! , gostaria de saber como que consigo fazer aquela animação de créditos no final do game , as letrinhas subindo ?

Comment: Por favor peço que faça uma questão nova e apresente aqui o link dessa questão para eu responder. O stackoverflow pede só uma questão por tópico. E se realmente o ajudei por favor feche o tópico, apresentando a minha resposta como solução. Obrigado

Comment: Como apresento sua resposta como solução ?

Comment: É so clicar no simbolo de tick/check , em baixo do rating da pergunta.

Comment: Poderia responder a minha pergunta acima?

Comment: Sim respondo com todo o gosto, mas por favor abra uma nova pergunta com esse tópico. Visto que é o método padrão do StackOverflow, 1 pergunta por tópico.

Comment: Está dando erro ao compilar .

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/boneco"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chara"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/boneco"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
    </ImageView>

Comment: Não seria necessário usar o ImageSwitcher ?

Comment: Mas desculpa o que pretendes fazer com a Imagem?